# Populating combobox with document fields

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm building a Java application connected to MongoDB about films, and I want to create a ComboBox so I can populate it with the film names. My problem is the only way I have found is populating it with the full document, instead of just getting the film name.

This is what I have so far:

```
DBCursor films = collection.find();     
while(films.hasNext()){
    comboBox.addItem(films.next());
}
```

This is how I create the document:

```
DBCollection table = db.getCollection("films");                  
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();

document.put("title", titulo.getText());
document.put("arg", argumento.getText());
document.put("date", fecha.getText());
document.put("genres", genres);

table.insert(document);
```

Is there a way to use find to only get the film titles and then display only the value? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

In the supposed duplicated question, the question is related to finding a specific document based on one of its fields. That's not what I need, I need to populate a combobox with one field, but I need to get all my documents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find some values in a mongodb collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327676/find-some-values-in-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate, I don't need to find a specific document, I need to list them all just getting one field.

Comment: what is your mongo db driver version ?

Comment: mongo-java-driver 3.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get only specific fields in your result set, you will need to use [`find(DBObject query, DBObject projection)`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-) and specify the fields to get in the projection parameter as next:

```
// Retrieve only the title of all the documents that can be found in the collection
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(
    new BasicDBObject(), new BasicDBObject("title", Boolean.TRUE)
);
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    // Add the value of the title to the combo box
    comboBox.addItem((String) cursor.next().get("title"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than do a find() pass in the keys you want returned. In this case I believe all you want back is the title. So this should work:

```
DBCursor films = collection.find({},{"_id":0,"title":1});     
while(films.hasNext()){
    comboBox.addItem(films.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DBObject` and `DBCollection` are old 2.x classes.

You can try something like with 3.x driver.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.*;

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
MongoCollection<Document> col = db.getCollection("films");

List<String> titles = col.find().projection(fields(include("titles"), excludeId())).map(document -> document.getString("titles")).into(new ArrayList<>());
```